# How to build standalone app with Qt?

Tags: windows, qt, cmd

I want to release a basic 'hello world' application but am getting errors when I try to follow the directions documented here:

http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Building_static_applications

1. The windows shell is completely different to me as a predominately linux user.  I don't know how to solve:

> 'configure' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Other failed attempts:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/deployment-windows.html
https://qt-project.org/wiki/Build_Standalone_Qt_Application_for_Windows

This can be as large as possible.  I care nothing about optimization, only that I can build a basic standalone app.

Qt 5.2.1
Windows 7

Comment: Well, whatever folder you're in, has no `configure.exe` in it. This will be the case if you've installed Qt from a tar file. Only the `.zip` file contains prebuilt `configure.exe`. You can also bootstrap configure by creating an empty `.gitignore` file within `qtbase`, and running `configure.bat` from the root folder of Qt sources.

Comment: I installed Qt from http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.2/5.2.0/qt-windows-opensource-5.2.0-mingw48_opengl-x86-offline.exe

Comment: So you have a prebuilt Qt. When you were installing it, did you install the sources? It seems like you didn't. Alas, there's no reason to use the offline installer at all, it will download a lot of unnessary stuff. All you need to build Qt is a supported compiler (MSVC2012 will suffice) and the `.zip` file with sources.